# The unit vectors a and b are such that $a\cdot b$ = $\frac{2}3$ . Determine the value of $a\cdot(a + 2b)$.

Tags: vectors

> The unit vectors a and b are such that $a\cdot b$ = $\frac{2}3$ . Determine the value
>   of $a\cdot(a + 2b)$.

Using distributive law:

$a\cdot(a+2b) = |a|^2 + 2a\cdot b$

$2a\cdot b = \frac{4}3$

Apparently $a.b$ is a unit vector but I don't understand how I would be able to tell this from the question.

Comment: $a\cdot b$ isn’t a vector at all—it’s a scalar.

Comment: unit vector means length 1.

Answer (score 1):

$$a \cdot (a+2b)$$
$$=||a||^2 + 2a \cdot b$$
$$=1 + 2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$$
$$=\frac{7}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $a,b$ are unit vectors, it means that : $|a|=|b|=1$

Then : $a(a+2b)=a^2 + 2ab$. There you have two dot products that work as |..|.

You get : $|a|^2 + 2ab = 1 + 2(\frac{2}{3}) = \frac{7}{3}$

Be careful that you understand things from that the $ab \neq 0 $